# Scotland Buspass or Railpass

Tags: budget, trains, tickets, buses, scotland

I am going to be traveling in Scotland in the beginning of March.  I will be traveling through Edinburgh, Stirling, Fort Williams, the Isle of Skye, and Inverness.  I had also planned on walking a portion of the Great Glen Way.

I am unable to decide between using trains or buses.  Which would be the better option based on cost, ease of use, comfort, and scenery?

Answer (score 6):

Rail wins out for ease-of-use, comfort, and scenery. Every city you mention is accessible by rail. You would have to transfer to bus only to get over the bridge from Kyle of Lochalsh to Skye. Rail is generally faster and more comfortable than bus - much faster and more comfortable on main lines, slightly more on secondary lines; and the scenery is usually better. The chance of going over one of the great railway bridges of Scotland is worth taking the train alone.

I don't know about cost, but I would imagine that is where the bus would win out.